# How do I calculate the size attributes for my tree elements in json?

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js

In many of the d3 visualization examples, the [flare.json](https://raw.github.com/devsar/d3talk/master/flare.json) is used as an example of a tree data structure, like this:

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
```

Each element in this example, except the root, has a size attribute. The size attribute is calculated according to its relative partition in the tree (i.e how many children, subschildren it has/does not have). Here is a [d3 example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html) where this size "attribute" is used to calculate the size of an element in a d3 tree graph.

My own data looks like this but does not have a size attribute. How can I calculate the size attributes for my data with a scripting language like python? Or do I even have to write it myself, can I do it a simpler, already made, way?

Comment: How is size attribute calculated? It's not clear from your example or from the linked flare.json. At least give a link to flare.json usage. From there it could be possible to guess what size attribute actually means.

Comment: I'm not sure I have this right?  Should the size attribute of every branch of your tree be essentially the count of the number of leaf nodes on the tree?  Or perhaps the number of total branches underneath it including leaves?  Or am I just, ahem, barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but probably you want to sum up the sizes of the sub-branches and take it as the size of the parent node (in case it does not already have one set already).  This would be done in Python like this:

```
def sizify(tree):
  children = tree.get('children', None)
  if children:
    children = [ sizify(child) for child in children ]
    size = (tree['size'] if 'size' in tree
      else sum(child['size'] for child in children))
  else:
    size = tree.get('size', 0)
  tree['size'] = size
  if children:
    tree['children'] = children
  return tree
```

For the tree above this gives sth like:

```
{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'name': 'AgglomerativeCluster',
                                           'size': 3938},
                                          {'name': 'CommunityStructure',
                                           'size': 3812},
                                          {'name': 'HierarchicalCluster',
                                           'size': 6714},
                                          {'name': 'MergeEdge',
                                           'size': 743}],
                             'name': 'cluster',
                             'size': 15207},
                            {'children': [{'name': 'BetweennessCentrality',
                                           'size': 3534},
                                          {'name': 'LinkDistance',
                                           'size': 5731},
                                          {'name': 'MaxFlowMinCut',
                                           'size': 7840},
                                          {'name': 'ShortestPaths',
                                           'size': 5914},
                                          {'name': 'SpanningTree',
                                           'size': 3416}],
                             'name': 'graph',
                             'size': 26435}],
               'name': 'analytics',
               'size': 41642}],
 'name': 'flare',
 'size': 41642}
```